# assign a bash script variable in local environment ssh commands

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I followed [this](http://thornelabs.net/2013/08/21/simple-ways-to-send-multiple-line-commands-over-ssh.html) tutorial for running several commands through ssh in bash script. But now I want to get the output of one of the commands that I am running through the ssh, save it in a variable and use in the next command.

```
 #!/bin/bash        
 ssh -t $VM_IP_ADDRESS bash -c "'

 export NET_ID=nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1

 nova boot $INSTANCE1_NAME --flavor m1.small --image $UBUNTU_IMAGE_NAME --key-name $KEY_PAIR_NAME --security-groups default --nic net-id=$NET_ID
'"
```

I want to set the NET_ID in my local environment and then use it in the next command. 
Now when I run this I get this error:

```
bash: line 17: export: `network-list': not a valid identifier
```

But I already checked and this command gives me the correct answer in the target machine.

```
nova network-list | egrep test_net | get_field 1
```

UPDATE:

With this command the NET_ID variable is setting in the target machine environment, but I wanted to set it in my local machin.

```
export NET_ID=\$(nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this (*a script run on your local machine*):

```
#!/bin/bash

user=<remote-username>
ip=<remote-ip>
SUBNET_NAME=<you-know-the-value>

export NET_ID=$(ssh $user@$ip "nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1")
# Now, do anything with the $NET_ID on your local machine.
```

*WARNING: the `NET_ID` variable will only be visible in your script and in any child process started by your script. You cannot export it to the parent environment (if that was the question).*

---

*Update: The solution that eventually worked for OP:*

```
NET_ID=$(ssh -t $VM_IP_ADDRESS bash -c "' \
<commands>
nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1; \
<commands> '")

echo $NET_ID
```

Comment: But if I do this it is going to try run these commands in my local machine. and I will get these errors:
./bashtest.sh: line 2: nova: command not found
./bashtest.sh: line 2: get_field: command not found

Comment: Try escaping the `$` sign: `export NET_ID=\$(nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1)`

Comment: So now this is exporting it in the target machine. Is it possible to export this variable in my local machine?

Comment: There is $SUBNET_NAME in that command that should be resolve in local machine so I should use it like this
ssh -t $VM_IP_ADDRESS bash -c "'
NET_ID=$(ssh $VM_IP_ADDRESS -c "'nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1'")
'"
which is not possible. I got this error:
Unknown cipher type ''nova network-list | egrep test_net | get_field 1''

Comment: @D3GAN: If double quotes are used instead of single quotes in the command passed to ssh, then SUBNET_NAME is resolved locally, not on your remote machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81342/discussion-between-eugeniu-rosca-and-d3gan).

Comment: At last we did it like this:
NET_ID=`ssh -t $VM_IP_ADDRESS bash -c "' \
....
nova network-list | egrep $SUBNET_NAME | get_field 1; \
....
'" `
echo $NET_ID